# Wordpress footer showing on the right sidebar.

Tags: php, html, wordpress, footer, sidebar

This is the site http://lettspropertymanagement.com/. The footer is showing on the right side which is the sidebar.

Using firebug, putting the footer div tags below more  lines solved the problem but in wordpress since its divided into different .php files which is the footer, sidebar etc. I cant do that.

What can i do http://lettspropertymanagement.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of the files sidebar.php which should really just have some sidebar content and footer.php. It might as well come from a non-closed html tag somewhere in index.php or content.php or loop.php depending on how your theme is made. From what i see in chrome's inspector is that your footer is inside your sidebar.

Comment: I know  i cant figure out which one tho

Comment: will be hard without having the code. Can you paste those (the ones i've listed above) in an online service like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) ?

Comment: You should clean the footer.php code, it's very messy. Get rid of the code you don't use instead of commenting it.

Comment: Same for footer.php, it's a real mess. Did you write that? Your footer starts in sidebar.php which makes no sense, you have lots of <br> tags which should be erased and replace by some css with `margin` for example, you have two `<div>` in an `<a>` tag and one of them isn't closed...